# Use the python interpreter packaged with py2exe

Tags: windows, py2exe, python

I have a python script I want to distribute to Windows, where people might not have python installed.  So I use py2exe.  The problem is in the script I run other python scripts by using subprocess, which requires python interpreter as the program to execute. As I don't have python interpreter installed on Windows, is there any way I could ignore the interpreter and work around the problem? Is there any way I could call the python interpreter pakcaged by py2exe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably more simple than you think: Instead of starting sub-processes, use the built-in `eval()` command to execute the scripts.

**[EDIT]** To redirect stdio, replace [sys.stdout/sys.stderr](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.stdin) with buffers or something else that supports "write()".

To restore the original values, the `sys` module offers `__stdout__`, etc.

**[EDIT2]** I haven't tried this but it might work: Add "python.exe" to the set of files which py2exe creates.

From the main code, copy all files that py2exe created + the python.exe into a temporary directory. Then add all your scripts.

Now start the new python interpreter with a small script that adds the temp folder and `library.zip` to the `sys.path`

Note: Python doesn't have to be "installed" like a Windows application. In fact, you can simply copy all the files to a new place. As long as the search path is correct, this works.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I could use eval, exec or execfile(this is probably the right one) to do it, but I tend to run it in another process as the main process is a PyQt program and I want to catch the output of the python script running in subprocess and show the output in main process.

Comment: One complication to be aware of: in this scenario, py2exe doesn't know what Python modules those `eval`ed scripts might need. You will need to tell py2exe to bundle any extra needed modules.

Comment: @Nick: redirect stdio and use a thread so it doesn't block. But there are other limitations (for example when the scripts call sys.exit()).

Comment: I've added another option which you can try.

Comment: Thanks that looks very promising. I'll try it and let you know.

Comment: I didn't try edit 1, because edit 2 worked! It's quite amazing because all I did was copy a python interpreter to the folder and set up sys.path.

Comment: Isn't it nice how simple many problems are to solve in Python? :-)

Comment: Hey I'm stuck in the same situation. Can you explain what do you mean with 'Add "python.exe" to the set of files which py2exe creates' ? Because I can't get a hang of it. I'm trying stuff like: console = [{'script': 'bin/app.py'},  'python.exe'] but this obviously fails. I have little experience with py2exe however.